# http daemon not responding

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, httpd

If I run a php file at the command prompt, it works as expected. But it does not load from browser.

```
# php /var/www/html/adminer.php
```

When I try to access the same file from browser, I get an error:

http://ec2-54-237-75-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com/adminer.php

I have checked that httpd is working. Port 80 is open and selinux is disabled.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

What else can be the reason if the page is not accessible from browser?

Update:

Here is apache error log...

```
[root@ip-10-140-30-124 html]# tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Mon Feb 10 01:04:11 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 10 01:09:11 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 10 01:12:38 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Feb 10 01:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Feb 10 01:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Feb 10 01:12:38 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: What were you supposed to see in this ?

Comment: php code output. In this case a simple form.

Comment: It seems to be working now, what did you do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

After disabling iptables, the web server worked as expected.

`/etc/init.d/iptables stop`